# Number of items in Redis set

Tags: count, redis, set

What's the easiest way to getting the number (count) of items in Redis set? Preferably without the need to dump whole set and count the lines... So far, I have found only BITCOUNT, which I have not found that useful...

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The SCARD command returns the cardinality (i.e. number of items) of a Redis set.

http://redis.io/commands/scard

There is a similar command (ZCARD) for sorted sets.

Comment: For errant seo: if you have a list (not a set) it's `llen`.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have a sorted set, you can use the [`ZCOUNT`](https://redis.io/commands/zcount) command to get the **number of elements in the sorted set** at key with a score between min and max.

Example:

`ZCOUNT myzset 2 15`

return count of elements with score >= 2 and <= 15

Answer (score 0):

for python you can use scard.

```
lebgth=db.scard(key)
```